# React page not loading due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

```jsx
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Recipes = props => (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            {props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
                return (
                    <div key={recipe.title} className="col-md-4" style={{ marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
                        <div className="recipes__box">
                            <img
                                className="recipe__box-img"
                                src={recipe.image_url}
                                alt={recipe.title} />
                            <div className="recipe__text">
                                <h5 className="recipes__title">
                                    {recipe.title.length < 20 ? `${recipe.title}` : `${recipe.title.substring(0, 25)}...`}
                                </h5>
                                <p className="recipes__subtitle">Publisher: <span>
                                    {recipe.publisher}
                                </span></p>
                            </div>
                            <button className="recipe_buttons">
                                <Link to={{
                                    pathname: `/recipe/${recipe.recipe_id}`,
                                    state: { recipe: recipe.title }
                                }}>View Recipe</Link>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default Recipes;
```

Can anyone please tell me why my .map() function is causing this error? This is the tutorial I am trying to follow (building a recipe react project)
Here is the source code:
https://github.com/hamza-mirza/react-recipe-app/blob/master/src/components/Recipe.js

Mine is identical as below but I get the TypeError.

Comment: it looks like your `recipes` prop is null at the first rendering. Try to add in your code `(props.recipes || []).map` and see if the error goes away

Comment: wow, this fixed it. thanks so much!

Comment: moving it to answer then

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `recipes` prop is null at the first rendering. 
Maybe you are passing something that is populated in an async way and at the first rendering is not there yet.

Try to add in your code:

`(props.recipes || []).map`

In order to have a safety check wrap, using an empty array if the prop `recipes` is `null` or `undefined` at the first renders

Answer (score 0):

Your recipes prop is null. Check what you're passing into the component.

Comment: this is not an answer or specially a solution. This should be a comment. You also have the reputation for commenting

Comment: "Can anyone please tell me why my .map() function is causing this error?" - this is a direct answer to that question.

Comment: if you think so, the error he has in the title: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null` is already a solution then